# CheckBox disable auto change of the Changed property

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to customize CheckBox's behavior. Clicking it should call a method that requests something from server. And some time later when the server answers a callback method should update the checkbox.

How can I disable auto change of the Changed property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class that extends `CheckBox`. Override the method `performClick()`. In that method you should request stuff from your server (asynchronously, please. don't lock up the UI). Remove the call to `super.performClick()` otherwise the CheckBox will get checked every time. Then updating the CheckBox when your server request returns is up to you.